# How to paste content from one file to anothe file in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, append

I have 2 files

```
export_f= open (../../sim_export/modelsim/compile.do)
comp_file = open (../../ver/sim/xilinx_compile.tcl)
```

I have to append the content of export_f after the 4 first lines of comp_file (all the lines after should be deleted)

Answer (score 0):

```
export_f= open ('compile.do', 'r')
comp_file = open ('xilinx_compile.tcl', 'r+')

with open('comp_file.temp', 'w') as temp:
    temp.writelines(comp_file.readlines()[0:4])
    temp.writelines(export_f)
```

This will create a new file named `comp_file.temp` that contains the first 4 lines of `comp_file` followed by all the contents of `export_f`.
It's also possible to replace the original `comp_file` with the new contents, or simply rename the new `comp_file.temp` to replace the original `comp_file`.

Hope this helps.